# EDMX file storage model is using self instead of fully qualified name

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having issue with the EF generated edmx file where SSDL is using self instead of Fully Qualified Name but CSDL and MSL are having FQN.

Here is the snapshot of code
**SSDL:**

```
  <Association Name="FK_CustomerOrders">
  <End Role="Customers" 
       Type="self.Customers" Multiplicity="1">
    <OnDelete Action="Cascade" />
  </End>
  </Association>
```

**CSDL and MSL:**

```
<Association Name="FK_CustomerOrders">
  <End Role="Customers" 
       Type="ExampleModel.Store.Customers" Multiplicity="1">
    <OnDelete Action="Cascade" />
  </End>
  </Association>
```

This is happening after we migrated solution from VS 2010 to VS 2013

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on the product's issue tracking site: https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/

Comment: I am not asking for feature change. In VS 2010 i used to get with FQN. After migration i am seeing self in SSDL. So i am looking for options to get FQN instead of self

Comment: Well, you're reporting a change. What can we do about it? It's the way it's implemented by EF. And then, you don't ask a question.